# Set custom date in Bootstrap Date Range Picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, date

I want to set custom date in Bootstrap Date Range Picker as default like this format below:

Format: **[today-7] - [today]**

So the first one will show the date 7 days ago from the current date as default and second one will show current date as default.

Here is the source file link of my work: http://securesofts.com/masum.zip

Here is the screenshot where I want it: [Date Range Picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSdaq.png)
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
$('input').daterangepicker(
  {
    locale: {
      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    },
    startDate: new Date(new Date().getTime() - (60*60*24*7*1000)),
    endDate: new Date
  }
)
```

Comment: what exactly is wrong? I wrote an example in fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/kgsa73hq/1/. As for me, it works fine.

Comment: Hi @cubbiu it is working fine, you are cool man, actually I did set id in the input, sorry for that.